# Help tracking down missing ETH

Tags: nft, mint

Tried minting a NFT using Coinbase Wallet. Transaction failed but the ETH (mint fee) is gone, any way to track it down?

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x042d8be1bea5a084498f88ce0a8e6a6fcef8bc420f79fd0c655fdbb81ce19b30

Answer (score 2):

The transaction has been reverted. Therefore any `value` (0.085 Eth) you provided to the transaction is returned to your wallet.

If it's not visible in your wallet, your wallet is out of sync or something like that. You can't lose that Eth in a reverted transaction.

The transaction gas costs (31,347 gas) will not be refunded.

Comment: Thanks! Yes took a while but wallet reflects the correct amount now